# Why did Google crawl this page?

Tags: joomla-3.3.x

I am not sure why Google crawled this page:
http://www.sonrisaseventos.com/component/content/featured.html?id=featured
. Featured should be the front page/home of http://www.sonrisaseventos.com/

Is this the correct behavior? Should I add /component/content/featured.html to robots.txt? I don't want to Google mark this as duplicate content that's my concern.

Joomla 3.3.6

Comment: Helpful info here: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4164/how-to-deal-with-duplicated-content-urls-in-joomla

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google will use URL parameters to crawl anything it can and you allow to find in a website. So this is an expected behavior for sites that have dynamically created pages.

These days Google is very smart and can identify the correct url for a page and will present this to any potential searcher. It really manages this pretty well.

In general if you are concerned about any **duplicate content penalty** for a case like this, you shouldn't. In a brief, Duplicate content penalty arrives when a website is copying content from others. This is what Google considers as duplicate content.

The only negative effect you might have, is a possible lose of page-rank for the page in question, because of the content existing in more than 1 pages.

Of course you can instruct Google to not index this page. Either by using **Canonical URLs** (should be your first option), either by **Blocking** it in the **Robots.txt**, or by tweaking the **URLs parameters** of Google crawler in **Google Webmasters Tools**.

Read also this answer, that explains the nature of dynamic pages: **[How to deal with Duplicated Content / URLs in Joomla?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4164/how-to-deal-with-duplicated-content-urls-in-joomla/5541#5541)**

Answer (score 0):

The following code placed in my .htaccess file worked for me on my Joomla 3.6.5 site.

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=featured$

RewriteRule ^component/content/featured.html?$ http://yoursite.com/? [L,R=301]