# How to prevent category pages from being visited

Tags: articles, category

Here is my problem, I made couple content categories, the structure is something like this:

- pages (here I store all the pages, like about us, contacts, news, privacy policy, etc);
- news (with subcategories to publish news into them);

I've also create a menu a linked it to singles articles from my pages category.

But if I try to access:

```
http://example.com/en/8-pages
http://example.com/en/about-us/8-pages
http://example.com/8-pages
```

etc. (where 8 is a "pages" category ID). I can see a page of the category itself and it display all the articles that I've inside that category. I've no idea how to prevent this. The category is just to store pages in it, it shouldn't be accessible. And I can't move my pages out of category either, cause there is Uncategorized category and this category can be viewed the same way (ID + category name) and viola.

Please help me to understand and fix this.

P.S. I did read the similar question [there](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10046/how-can-i-get-rid-of-category-pages-in-joomla), but I find my question different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using joomla redirects or HTACCESS redirects for that.
Whenever x category is requested you redirect to the user to page x