# Category Blog Allows Viewing of all Categories

Tags: joomla-3.6, category, search, category-blog

I have a Category Blog Menu Item where I have chosen all articles with category News to be displayed and layed out how I like. However, by creating just one Category Blog menu item on my site, now all categories can be viewed by manipulating the URL.

So if I go to the URL `www.site.com/news/18-bsm`, it shows articles with my BSM category, where 18 is the category's ID. I only want my Category Blog to allow users to access articles under the News category.

While there are no links to these other category URLs in my site, they still exist and are showing up in my site's search results. Is there any way to disable these other categorys from being accessed this way? Such as a way to only allow users to access the article content through menu links, not through this URL manipulation.

I'm running Jooma 3.6.5 by the way.

Comment: I think the answers will be similar to those outlined here https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10046/how-can-i-get-rid-of-category-pages-in-joomla and https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4164/how-to-deal-with-duplicated-content-urls-in-joomla