# News Module not redirecting to correct place

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, menu-item, module-display, url, itemid

Hi All On our home page we have a latest news module that you click through to to read an article in the blog. http://se24media.net/adnitt/ Unfortunately when you click through I wanted it to display the modules that are visible on the right when you click news and views page from the top menu. I had this issue with another site and it was simple to fix, but I cannot remember how i did it! The module on the front page is Gavick News Show Pro GK5 Thanks!less

Comment: You really should read the instructions.
https://www.gavick.com/documentation/joomla-extensions/extensions-for-joomla-1-6/news-show-pro-gk5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create **Menu items** and assign the modules and other layout settings you want for the items or their category.

Assuming the latest news module fetches articles from 1 or more content categories, then creating menu items for each of the articles will not be the solution.

Instead you need to create a **Menu item** for the **category** of these articles. You probably would like to have the menu item not being displayed in your main menu, so create first a new menu in Menu Manager - and name it **Hidden**.
Then add to it the new menu item of type category blog layout for the category of the articles you show in the latest news module.

Lastly, you can go in module manager and select which modules you want to show under this menu item.

Now, when you click the titles of the articles in the Latest News Module, it will open the articles under the menu item id you just created and will also display the modules you assigned for this menu item.

#### Update after having a quick look at your site:

I saw at least 2 child categories under blog.

So, you probably have 1 parent category "Blog" and a few other children of it.

One possible configuration specific for your site would be:
 - Create the **Hidden** menu as described. - Name it **Hidden-Blog**.
 - Start creating **menu items** for this menu.
 - First create a **category blog layout menu item** for the parent category, name it "**Blog**".
 - Then add **one category blog layout menu item** for each of the **children categories** - name the menu items, same as your categories - Make these items **children** of the Blog Menu Item.
 - Finally, in **module manager** assign your modules accordingly.

*I think this might be a duplicate question and has already an answer in JSE, but can't spot it right now.

Comment: Wonderful thank you very much. it was very obvious after you explain it and it is now working. Thanks again!