# K2 Different Url same item

Tags: joomla-2.5, k2, seo

I can't manage how to solve this problem with K2.

I have had a problem regarding this url: mysite.com/category/1/item-1 and mysite.com/category/item-1 and I managed to solve it using the .htaccess file but now I discovered 2 more problems:

1) mysite.com/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=X:my-item&Itemid=Y is equal to mysite.com/category/my-item

2) mysite.com/component/k2/my-item is equal to mywebsite.com/category/my-item

3) mysite.com/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&layout=item&id=X is equal to mywebsite.com/category/my-item

I already have enabled my URL SEF options in joomla configuration, of course.

This will cause a duplicate item issue that may hurt my SEO. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 & 2 are equal but they won't exist together with SEF URLs.
Although you will still be able reach to a page using a non-SEF URL with SEF enabled, but there will be nothing on your website that will denote or use the non-sef urls.

In addition **Google** is smart enough and will index the SEF URLs of your site, even if it can reach to them using URL parameters. It's always worthing to have a Google Webmasters Account, where you can monitor how Google sees your content and many more. In there you can also instruct how Google crawler should behave with [**URL parameters**](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080550?hl=en) found in your site.

Also find out more about the [**Duplicate Content**](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080548?hl=en)

The above is the common scenario, that assumes anything else is properly configured on your site.

Regarding 2, you need to ensure that your k2 categories and items are reachable through a menu item, in order to avoid getting urls with the word "component" as path.

Furthermore you many want to read here about "[**Dealing with Duplicate Content**](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4164/how-to-deal-with-duplicated-content-urls-in-joomla/5541#5541)".