# What is generating links in Joomla?

Tags: joomla-3.x, zoo

How or where could I refresh the links that were generated in menu?

I have currently a problem with links, because for some reason some aditional suffix is generated.

This is my current link:
www.mysite.com/en/article-categories-view/article-category/company/about-us.html

I have no idea from where this comes : article-categories-view/article-category ?

I want that my links look like this: 
www.mysite.com/en/company/about-us.html

Interesting thing is some link are generated right and some not. How could i force Joomla te recreate links once again.

Comment: This post here, although not directly answers your question, it can give you a basic understanding about urls generation in dynamic websites: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4164/how-to-deal-with-duplicated-content-urls-in-joomla

Answer (score 1):

Depends on whether you use SEF extensions or not.

If not - then all links are never cached.
How the links are generated: closest in hierarchy page that is assigned to menu item found, Joomla takes it URL and adds up aliasses of categories according to hierarchy, and article alias added at the end if needed.

If you do: manage links(SEF URLs) with whatever extension you got - JoomSEF, sh404sef, etc.

If you use multiple SEF extensions then you need to debug which of them is in control.

Answer (score 1):

You can check two locations.
First try check the category and subcategory on your content about-us was saved. 
Second try check your menu item link to your file about-us.

Joomla use this logical to create the sef urls.

I hope this helps.