# Remove Link that is not in menu

Tags: menu, menu-item, weblinks

I have a website that can be accessed by an unknown link under the website. For example there is an /unrelated-link under my domain and it can access the website.

To illustrate:

> www.domain.com/unrelated-link

Although it seems like it is under the menu of the page, I can't seem to find it in the menu manager of Joomla. Is there anyway to remove that? Or is there a sort of website mapping file where I could remove it? A sort of web.xml kind of thing?

Comment: hard to say, it can be many things... apart of core joomla sef, do you have any other sef extensions? can you share the actual link?

Comment: I do not have any other SEF installed. Here are the links: http://holyinfantjesusmanila.com/6v-written-assignment-text-types/
http://holyinfantjesusmanila.com/9jft-research-paper-example-child-abuse/

Comment: If you have access to phpmyadmin, I would select that database and just do a search across all tables for 6v-written-assignment-text-types and see what it comes up with.

Comment: I have manually searched for it in each table, but there are no references there

Comment: What content is displayed under that link? Do you have some 3rd party SEO extension?

Answer (score 1):

One of the best explanations why do we have multiple URLs in Joomla, and how to deal with it, you can find here on JSE:
[How to deal with Duplicated Content / URLs in Joomla?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4164/how-to-deal-with-duplicated-content-urls-in-joomla)