# duplicate content for an article URLs

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, seo, content

look at the URLs below:

```
1. /essays/technical-essays/180-technologies/247-megapixel
2. /essays/technical-essays/247-megapixel
3. /essays/technical-essays/technologies/247-megapixel
4. /essays/technical-essays/technologies/247-
```

the right URL is the third one. but the product page shows up with other three URLs. notice that the other three are incorrect and incomplete and an 404 error should be thrown.

don't get this in a wrong way. it's not about canonical more than one direction to a page. it's about inputting wrong (incomplete) URL of an article and having the article page open. weird!!

what is this? why this happens?

google console finds these as different pages and refers to them as "Duplicate title tags"

Comment: I think this Q/A will answer all your questions: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4164/how-to-deal-with-duplicated-content-urls-in-joomla?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

It is a known problem. There may be several reasons. Among other things, how have you made your menus.
You can fix it by redirecting to the unwanted URLs.

There are several extensions that can help solve the problem. I have very good experiences with RSSeo from RSJoomla, which gives a good overview.